# ASP MVC 302 status redirect instead of POST processing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have next specific map routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "MyPagePost",
             "URL-Up/{name}",
               new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyPostAction" },
               new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "MyPageGet",
                "URL-Up/{name}",
                  new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyGetAction" },
                  new { name = "[A-Za-z].+", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
           );
```

my default controller looks like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { culture = @"[a-zA-Z]{2}" }
                );
```

FORM in HTML looks like

```
<form action="/URL-Up/Bla-Bla" id="myid" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
</form>
```

and the issue is next:

In Chrome or fiddler Logs I see that reqvest to  `URL-Up/Bla-Bla` has 302 status and response header is redirect to *URL-Up/Bla-Bla?culture=de*. Why it can't be processed ?

Comment: Do you have any URL rewrite rules in IIS or redirects in the controller action/action filters?

Comment: it is 100% not in IIS, about actions I am not using it for this particular issue

Comment: @Jason Evans The goal is to have URL-Up with any  /{name} after. + the main issue I need to keep url name after postBack.

Answer (score 0):

after different way I finally epiphany solve the issue I write the same controller method name MyGetAction with httppost attribute and it is working